# Run multi inkscape commands in one line

Tags: php, inkscape

Is it possible to run multiple commands in one exec command? I need to grab some images from SVG files and this variant is too slow:

```
exec('inkscape file.svg --export-id=g123 --export-png=img1.png');
exec('inkscape file.svg --export-id=g124 --export-png=img2.png');
exec('inkscape file.svg --export-id=g125 --export-png=img3.png');
```

So I need to do everything in one line. I've already tried this:

```
exec('inkscape file.svg --export-id=g125 --export-png=img3.png inkscape file.svg --export-id=g123 --export-png=img1.png');
```

But this extracts only the last image.

Answer (score 2):

`exec()` itself is not slow. But with each call, you first start Inkscape, perform the operation and close it again. That is, what takes so long.

Unfortunately, Inkscape doesn't have a batch mode. Bu you could use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), which can do the same operation in batch.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Inkscape in shell mode and communicate with it by writing commands to its stdin. If you don't want to implement it in PHP you could write a simple shell wrapper that does it 
for you, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
SVG="$1"
shift
(
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do
  echo "\"--file=$SVG\" \"--export-id=$1\" \"--export-png=$2\""
  shift 2
done
echo "quit"
) | \
  /path/to/inkscape --shell 2>/dev/null
```

And then use it like this

```
exec("/path/to/wrapper file.svg g123 img1.png g124 img2.png g125 img3.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

exec() is probably not slow. Server/inkscape is slow.